# showing custom calculations in tableau

Tags: tableau-api

I am pretty new to Tableau and have to create a report quickly.

I want to add a row level 'custom' calculation for a select # of rows in Tableau report.

Can you help me figure it out?

e.g.refer to attached image

Comment: show your code which you tried ...

Answer (score 0):

First create new calculation field

[image]

Add INDEX() in calculation and drag it to raw

[image]